# How to open a link as Tab in same webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, jquery-ui

I have seen many web applications which contains single web window with many links. On clicking the links concerned form gets open as new tab in the same web page of the application. So my concern is how to get that?

How to get the link open as new tab and later can be closed in the same window?

Comment: @intracept I am not getting how to start with..No keywords in knowledge for it.

Comment: just surf the web you will get lot of options for this.till you didnt get.then post your worked code.

Comment: can you give an example of any such web application? only then we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one example that may help you get on your way to add dynamic tabs:

http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/layout/tabs2.php

I'm sure there are others.

Comment: Just posting links as an answer is considered bad on the SE network. The answer should stand on it's own in case the link dies. You can always add additional links to your answer as long the answer can stand on it's own.

Comment: @MennoGouw Fair comment, I'll make sure that next time I do that.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using target option

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Visit facebook </a>
```

There are many option for this.

1. _blank Opens the linked document in a new window or tab.
2. _self Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default).
3. _parent Opens the linked document in the parent frame.
4. _top Opens the linked document in the full body of the window.
5. framename Opens the linked document in a named frame.

Comment: He asks for a tab that can be closed in the same window, so your answer isn't right.

Comment: he ask for a tab that can be opened in same window..if u open in same window then it is very easy to close in same tab...for any other help plz comment @daan heskes